# Swift Background Notifications Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, background, notifications

I am working on my background Notifications where the user should get informed in case of any event happening (like, comment, follow etc.)

I have a function that checks if a child was added on the database in the users notification, which works more or less fine.

My problem is that the function to check the new Childs in the firebase database does not work always.
I call the function in all types in the appDelegate

```
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    API.pushNotifications.checkNewFollow()
}
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    API.pushNotifications.checkNewFollow()

}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    API.pushNotifications.checkNewFollow()
}
```

But it does not always and not infinitely long check the database. It seems to me that after a certain time, it stops checking for updates on the database.
More over it does not work when I start the app the first time, I always have to refresh my main view unless it works.

Any idea on how to perform these task better? 
How do you handle the background task? 
I am happy about any tip!

Answer (score 0):

ios app doesn't run in background for long time i think you should have backend service which schedule notification and when app in background or terminated it will inform that user 
so instead of the app calling firebase database you set flag in firebase that this user is not active any more and the scheduler will track and notify this user 
you can use quartz.net for scheduling if your server is windows
or create cron job for linux server

Comment: the thing is when I send a cloud message from firebase it always receives it immediately